# NSCFData objectForKey unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have a iOS app that should detect the artwork within a .mp3 file via the ID3 tags, it used to work but its been crashing when ever i click the mp3 and the audio player tries to start (because it should display the artwork)

If i comment out these two lines of code, it won't crash anymore

```
NSData *data = [(NSDictionary *)[item value] objectForKey:@"data"];
self.imgArtwork setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];
```

Here's the whole snippet of code

```
-(void) updateUserInterfaceForTrack
{

    if (isPodCastPlaying) {
        [self.imgArtwork setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"microphone_large"]];
        [self.imgThumbnail setImage:self.imgArtwork.image];
        [self.lblSongTitle setText:[AppHandler sharedInstance].currentPodcastObject.artist];
        [self.lblSongTitle2 setText:self.lblSongTitle.text];
        [self.lblSongArtist setText:[AppHandler sharedInstance].currentPodcastObject.artist];
        [self.lblAlbum setText:[AppHandler sharedInstance].currentPodcastObject.show];
    }
    else
    {

        if (self.mPlayerItem) {
            NSArray *metadata = [[self.mPlayerItem asset] commonMetadata];

            //for (NSString *format in [assest availableMetadataFormats]) {
            for (AVMetadataItem *item in metadata) {
                //NSLog(@"%@",item);
                if ([[item commonKey] isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
                    //filename.text = (NSString *)[item value];
                    self.lblSongTitle.text = (NSString *)[item value];
                    self.lblSongTitle2.text = self.lblSongTitle.text;
                    //NSLog(@" title : %@", (NSString *)[item value]);
                }
                if ([[item commonKey] isEqualToString:@"artist"]) {
                    //show_id.text = (NSString *)[item value];
                    self.lblSongArtist.text = (NSString *)[item value];

                    //NSLog(@" artist : %@", (NSString *)[item value]);
                }
                if ([[item commonKey] isEqualToString:@"albumName"]) {
                    //  _albumName = (NSString *)[item value];
                    //NSLog(@" albumName : %@", (NSString *)[item value]);
                    self.lblAlbum.text = (NSString *)[item value];
                }

                if ([[item commonKey] isEqualToString:@"artwork"]) {
                    NSData *data = [(NSDictionary *)[item value] objectForKey:@"data"];
                    [self.imgArtwork setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];
                    [self.imgThumbnail setImage:self.imgArtwork.image];
                    NSLog(@" artwork found ");
                }
            }
            //}
        }

        if (self.lblSongTitle.text.length == 0) {
            NSString *fileName = [[self.currentUrl lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
            fileName = [fileName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%20" withString:@" "];
            [self.lblSongTitle setText:fileName];
            self.lblSongTitle2.text = self.lblSongTitle.text;
        }

        if (self.lblAlbum.text.length == 0) {
            [self.lblAlbum setText:@"Unknown"];
        }

        if (self.lblSongArtist.text.length == 0) {
            [self.lblSongArtist setText:@"Unknown"];
        }
    }

    [self.lblTracksInfo setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld of %lu",(long)currentIndex+1,(unsigned long)[self.arrTracks count]]];

    //[self.lblSongTitle setText:[title.value copyWithZone:nil]];
    //[self.lblSongArtist setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@",[artist.value copyWithZone:nil],[albumName.value copyWithZone:nil]]];

    /*if (![AppHandler sharedInstance].isLocal) {
     [_btnDownload setHidden:false];
     }else
     [_btnDownload setHidden:YES];
     */
}
```

And here's the Error Logs:

```
2015-12-31 03:05:42.657 GypsyChurch[730:173717] -[__NSCFData objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13dac4560
2015-12-31 03:05:42.658 GypsyChurch[730:173717] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFData objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13dac4560'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x183bdd900 0x18324bf80 0x183be461c 0x183be15b8 0x183ae568c 0x10005e574 0x100060d50 0x1844c8804 0x1844c832c 0x1844b2b44 0x189dfb7a8 0x189e0f6b0 0x1001a1bf0 0x1001a1bb0 0x1001a7658 0x183b94bb0 0x183b92a18 0x183ac1680 0x184fd0088 0x188938d90 0x10008d1dc 0x1836628b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I'd Aprecheate any help, Also i'd like to mention i did have some help making this app... so my skill level is limited.. so simple explanations please ;-)

Thank You!

Comment: Log the [item value] value.. You are type casting it to NSDictionary , and from error it seems like [item value]  is not a dictionary. Can you please log  [item value] and update the question

Comment: @Muneeba how do i log [item value]?

Comment: NSLog(@"Item value %@",[item value]);

Comment: @Muneeba Like this?                 if ([[item commonKey] isEqualToString:@"artwork"]) {
                    NSData *data = [(NSDictionary *)[item value] objectForKey:@"data"];
                    [self.imgArtwork setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];
                    [self.imgThumbnail setImage:self.imgArtwork.image];
                    NSLog(@" artwork found ");
                    NSLog(@"Item value %@",[item value]);
                }

Comment: @Muneeba do you have Skype? and ill share my screen with you?

Comment: NSData *data = [item dataValue]; try this

Comment: @Muneeba on the line for                     NSData *data = [(NSDictionary *)[item value] objectForKey:@"data"]; its saying "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" does that help any?

Comment: @MuhammadZohaibEhsan i added that like this NSData *data = [(NSDictionary *)[item dataValue] objectForKey:@"data"]; and I'm still getting the same error: NSData *data = [(NSDictionary *)[item dataValue] objectForKey:@"data"];

Comment: just add the line which i wrote don't type cast it or anything :)

Comment: @MuhammadZohaibEhsan it worked!!! Thank you!!

Comment: :) Please refer to AVMetadataItem documentation for more info
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVMetadataItem_Class/

Comment: Yeah @MuhammadZohaibEhsan is right.. thats why i asked you log the [item value], the error was coming because you were performing a dictionary operation on variable of type NSData.

Comment: Yep u are right @Muneeba

Comment: @MuhammadZohaibEhsan Thank you!